# Hide product categories from WooCommerce search

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I Need help please I have to hide Multiple product categories from my WordPress, WooCommerce, search and admin, This Coding is not working for me at all:

```
function exclude_product_categories( $q ) {
    $excluded_cats = array(
        3233, 3254, 3244, 1990, 3120, 3129, 3121, 2717, 2718, 2355,
        3314, 2356, 3040, 3312, 2978, 2357, 3125, 3117, 2358, 1994,
        3333, 1995, 2998, 2699, 3123, 2714, 2700, 1991, 3330, 3324,
        1992, 3325, 2862, 3122, 3328, 2013, 3156, 2364, 2479, 3246,
        2701, 3256, 3166, 2698, 2353, 3115, 3116, 3251, 3329, 3331,
        3250, 2010, 2011, 2171, 2715, 2796, 2980, 2981, 3124, 3255,
        3243, 2894, 1984, 1985, 1986, 3231, 3101, 3105, 3102, 3109,
        3103, 2418, 2419, 3253, 2814, 3170, 1987, 1988, 2015, 2996,
        2017, 3012, 2989, 2570, 3234, 2571, 2006, 2007, 2004, 3230,
        2012, 2695, 2864, 3235, 3005, 2466, 2908, 2909, 2910, 2008,
        2682, 2786, 2991, 2812, 2019, 2020, 2900, 2791, 3241, 3238,
        3357, 3358, 2904, 2905, 3245, 2893, 2459, 2795, 2906, 2897,
        2907, 2684, 3153, 3104, 2902, 3240, 2349, 2350, 2351, 3377,
        3161, 3162, 3247, 3248, 3376, 3249, 3239, 1996, 2001, 2792,
        2912, 2002, 2990, 2003, 2567, 2568, 2374, 2375, 2456, 3257,
        3154, 1999, 2354, 2000, 2895, 3164, 2896, 2021, 3293, 2022,
        3155, 3147, 3167, 3313, 2697, 2911, 2457, 3237, 2901, 2683,
        2898, 2903, 2719, 2793, 2794, 2876, 2877, 2720, 2995, 3252,
        1193, 1205, 1201, 1203, 1511, 3480, 1697, 3165, 1250, 1734,
        1899, 1874, 1729, 1853, 1204, 3363, 1176
    );

    if( ( $q->is_post_type_archive('product') || $q->is_tax('product_cat') ) && $q->is_main_query() ) {
        $tax_query = (array) $q->get('tax_query');
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $excluded_cats,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
        $q->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_categories' );
```

But the code doesn't work. What I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does the code works or not? Can you update your question please, as it's unclear.

Comment: This code does not work sadly and I do not understand why it does not work for me.

Comment: Do you want to hide that categories only on frontend WooCommerce search and in admin product list? or also in Wordpress search?

Comment: I want to hide if from the front end search and admin product list yes that is correct.

Comment: The rule on Stack overflow is one question at the time… Your question is really not clear and include multiple questions at once.

Answer (score 1):

Udated

There are some few mistakes in your code. To hide products belonging to specific product categories from frontend search, use:

```php
// Settings: Here your product categories array
function hidden_product_categories() {
    return array(
        3233, 3254, 3244, 1990, 3120, 3129, 3121, 2717, 2718, 2355,
        3314, 2356, 3040, 3312, 2978, 2357, 3125, 3117, 2358, 1994,
        3333, 1995, 2998, 2699, 3123, 2714, 2700, 1991, 3330, 3324,
        1992, 3325, 2862, 3122, 3328, 2013, 3156, 2364, 2479, 3246,
        2701, 3256, 3166, 2698, 2353, 3115, 3116, 3251, 3329, 3331,
        3250, 2010, 2011, 2171, 2715, 2796, 2980, 2981, 3124, 3255,
        3243, 2894, 1984, 1985, 1986, 3231, 3101, 3105, 3102, 3109,
        3103, 2418, 2419, 3253, 2814, 3170, 1987, 1988, 2015, 2996,
        2017, 3012, 2989, 2570, 3234, 2571, 2006, 2007, 2004, 3230,
        2012, 2695, 2864, 3235, 3005, 2466, 2908, 2909, 2910, 2008,
        2682, 2786, 2991, 2812, 2019, 2020, 2900, 2791, 3241, 3238,
        3357, 3358, 2904, 2905, 3245, 2893, 2459, 2795, 2906, 2897,
        2907, 2684, 3153, 3104, 2902, 3240, 2349, 2350, 2351, 3377,
        3161, 3162, 3247, 3248, 3376, 3249, 3239, 1996, 2001, 2792,
        2912, 2002, 2990, 2003, 2567, 2568, 2374, 2375, 2456, 3257,
        3154, 1999, 2354, 2000, 2895, 3164, 2896, 2021, 3293, 2022,
        3155, 3147, 3167, 3313, 2697, 2911, 2457, 3237, 2901, 2683,
        2898, 2903, 2719, 2793, 2794, 2876, 2877, 2720, 2995, 3252,
        1193, 1205, 1201, 1203, 1511, 3480, 1697, 3165, 1250, 1734,
        1899, 1874, 1729, 1853, 1204, 3363, 1176
    );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_categories' );
function exclude_product_categories( $q ) {
    if ( $q->is_search() && ! is_admin() ) {
        $tax_query = (array) $q->get('tax_query');

        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => hidden_product_categories(),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );

        $q->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
    }
}
```

Now to hide product categories themselves, it's something completely different, so you should ask a (some) new question(s), better explaining things and specifying which related plugins you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much for the super quick response on this but unfortunately the code you provided did not work either and can still see the categories both front and back end.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my code.

Comment: This new updated code did something strange now.

I can see that I still have 2000 products under the published tab, but they are no longer visible on the back end so this is both good and bad thing.
Because the products are not visible i cannot edit or modify them.
But the categories itself still show in woocommerce categories on the back and the front end.

Guessing there might be a conflict between my B2B API plugin and Woocommerce

Comment: To hide product categories themselves, it's something completely different, so you should ask a new question better explaining things and specifying which related plugins you are using. Nobody can guess things by magic. The rule on Stack overflow is one question at the time, if you don't want your question to be closed as too broad.

Comment: Sorry for asking but what do you mean something different?
I had listed code that contains Product Categories ID's and listed that i want to hide the product categories both front and back end. 
But i am somewhat new to the wordpress and coding but its not impossible that i might have the wrong code.
What do i then need to achieve hiding the product categories and what question should i be asking?

Comment: product category is a custom taxonomy, and the query to be used is a term query
and for products the query is a post query. I still don't understand what you want to do...  "pre_get_post" hook is made to alter displayed products, but not displayed categories.

Answer (score 1):

Using get_terms_args you can exclude terms globaly.

```
function exclude_terms_by_ids($args) {
    // Define an array of term IDs to exclude.
    $excluded_term_ids = array(1,2,3); // Replace with the IDs you want to exclude.

    $args['exclude'] = $excluded_term_ids;

    return $args;
}
add_filter('get_terms_args', 'exclude_terms_by_ids', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Yes, that is the right way for terms query, But as you can see the question is really confused and unclear. Additionally, the OP is using other 3rd party plugins that are interfering.

Comment: Yes i read all the comments on your answer and indeed its unclear :d